# Django Validator function is not called in models file

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, model

i have models department when i add validator it does not call validator function

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, validators=[lookups_name_validator])
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    organization_id = models.ForeignKey(Organizations,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=1)
```

my validators

```
from django.core.validators import ValidationError
import re

def lookups_name_validator(branch):
    pattern = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_&/.\-]*$")
    match = re.match(pattern, branch)
    if match is None:
        raise ValidationError(
            f'{branch} is not Valid'
        )
```

my view is contain on Classed based API view

Comment: The model does not run the validators by default, this is normally the task of the serializer/form.

Comment: what will be alternative of this ??

Comment: The way this is normally done is working with a *serializer*...